# How to validate false on only numbers via regex?

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to validate a domain registration as it cannot be made of numbers only and the validation need to fit in the way my algorithm works, that is to return full domain name(without the .com, .net, etc extensions) if it is correct.

I've tryed a few expressions with no success:

```
^[^0-9]+$ # that one wont let he type a number
^\w[^0-9]+\w$ # that wont work too
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should be more precise on your validation needs...

Comment: Domain names are more complex to validate by regex than you might realise. Googling "regex domain name" and you'll get lots of options though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, just to be clear, you want it to return False on strings that contain ONLY numbers? Try this:

**EDIT 4** Based on literal interpretation of the question, this is all you need:

```
\D
```

That will match True for any string containing a character that's not a number.

However, based on the fact that you want to match URLs, you probably want something more like this:

```
^\w*[a-zA-Z_]\w*$
```

That will match any string containing alphanumerics and `_`s, as long as it contains at least one letter or `_`.

Comment: I will use yours a bit diferent: `^[\w\.\-]*[a-zA-Z][\w\.\-]*$`

Answer (score 1):

You want al least one character that isn't digit. So: `^.*[^0-9].*$`.

If you want just letters (but not whole `.`), you need to lookahead: `^\w*(?![0-9])\w\w*$`, means: no digit, but letter.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=.*\D)
```

Use lookahaed. This will fail if the string consists of digits only.

Comment: But it'll allow `%#%#%#!@`, which the question, probably, wants to avoid.

Comment: @Y.Shoham I don't "work" with probabilities. OP said he wants something to fail if it consists only of digits. That's what I provided. Without input/output I can't provide a better example.

Comment: You're right. But he said he want to "validate a domain registration", so `!@#` are bad. For real uses, we need to the full specs of it.